# How to show route between a MKPointAnnotation and user's current location in swift 2

Tags: swift2, location, mapkit

I am trying to show the route between a MKPointAnnotation and user's current location, but i am fail with it.

My idea is: getting user's current location ->  getting the MKPointAnnotation' Coordinate -> line up with MKPolylineRenderer

The problem is that i cannot find the problem. :(  I have no idea where i should modify.

```
class MapInSearch: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
     var destination: MKMapItem?
     var coords: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var PlaceLat = ""
    var PlaceLong = ""// get from previous view controller



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        // For use in foreground
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }// step 1 

        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        self.mapView.delegate = self
       self.addRoute() // step 2
    }

    func addRoute() {
        var pointsToUse: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

        if PlaceLat != "" || PlaceLong != "" {
        let coords = "\(PlaceLat), \(PlaceLong)"
        let p = CGPointFromString(coords)
        pointsToUse += [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(p.x), CLLocationDegrees(p.y))]
        }
      pointsToUse += [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(coords!.latitude), CLLocationDegrees(coords!.longitude))]
        let myPolyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &pointsToUse, count: 2)
        mapView.addOverlay(myPolyline)

    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
            let lineView = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            lineView.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            return lineView // step 3 
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      self.coords = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(coords!.latitude) \(coords!.longitude)")
    }
```

My code is very disorderly because i mixed 4-5 tutorials. Also, these tutorials is written with swift 1.2.(i have tried to edit it to swift 2, but i am fail)

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever resolve your problem? Using the latest iteration of Swift 2 in XCode 7.3, in your view (we will call it MyViewController):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.mapView.delegate = self

    var coordinates : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [];
    addRoute(coordinates);       
}

func addRoute(coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {

    // insert your code to populate coordinates array with your coordinates
    polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
    self.mapView.addOverlay(polyLine, level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveRoads)
}
```

Then in the same file:

```
extension MyViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let pr = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay);
        pr.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5);
        pr.lineWidth = 5;
        return pr;
    }
}
```

You may find the important part was the extension. I haven't tested this code, so feel free to correct any issues that crept in.

Answer (score 0):

in your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` delegate function `didUpdateLocations` you can update your location by setting
`self.myLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation`

Then call `MakeRoute()` - This is a function i wrote to either make a route by car or by walking (hence the `self.driveIsSet`)

```
func makeRoute()  {
        let startPlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: myLocation.coordinate)
        let endPlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: restLocation.coordinate)

        let startMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: startPlaceMark)
        let endMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: endPlaceMark)

        let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        directionRequest.source = startMapItem
        directionRequest.destination = endMapItem
        if self.driveIsSet {
            directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
        } else {
            directionRequest.transportType = .walking
        }


        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
        directions.calculate { (routeResponse, routeError) in
            guard let routeResponse = routeResponse else {
                if let routeError = routeError {
                    print(routeError)
                }
                return
            }
            self.mapView.removeOverlays(self.mapView.overlays)
            let route = routeResponse.routes[0]
            self.mapView.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)
        }
    }
```